# Vite static asset path on build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, rollup

I have the below array

```
const imagePaths = [
  `../assets/icons/WSD-Website-Feature-Icon-Market-Trends-`,
  `../assets/icons/WSD-Website-Feature-Icon-Market-Trends-`,
];
```

and I have the following function

```
const getImageUrl = (path, color = "white") => {
    let url = `${path}${color}.svg`;
    return new URL(url, import.meta.url).href;
};
```

and I call this function like so

```
:src="getImageUrl(imagePaths[index],'red')"
```

When on development mode in Vite this works fine and I can see the images display but after build I get a 404. From what I can see it is referencing the correct path "/assets/icons" but the "icons" folder doesn't exist in the dist directory.

I have also tried moving the icons folder into /public but I still run into the same issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried a few options and also read the vite static asset handling documentation at https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html

Comment: I also had an issue with loading images in production build especially, if the assets are served from a different location. There is an Issue on the vite github repo, that you might want to look into: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/10842

Comment: Have you confirmed that the "base" is what you need it to be? https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base ... should be in the: export default defineConfig section of your vite.config.js file. Documentation is a bit unclear on this. This may or may not help. Hope it does, lmk